# How to migrate from jQuery Mobile 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: jquery-mobile

Now that the JQM 1.1 RC is out, I would like to migrate my 1.0 mobile app to this 1.1 version. How can I do that? Do I have to replace every file or just some specific files? What should be my migration path?

**Edit**: I plan to use my app using PhoneGap, which means, that I will want to have all resources locally, so no external references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your jqm css and js references. Also, you'll need jquery 1.7.1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0- rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js">    </script>
```

Comment: I want to have all the resources locally (I edited my question), so I would probably also need to download images (like the new loading animation), etc.? Which ones?...

Comment: Just the css files and js

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.zip

You can get jquery here

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: Also, order of the js files is important http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html
... same as with 1.0